# Listen for Google Calendar resource changes without server

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-googleapiclient

I need to somehow be notified in realtime when a Calendar resource (like a room) has a change made to it (new event, event deleted, event modified, etc.) Now, I know the Google Calendar API allows registration of notifications (https://developers.googleblog.com/2013/07/google-calendar-api-push-notifications.html). The problem is, this requires the URL of a server to receive the notification in JSON. I don't have a server! I'm only writing an Android app - there is no third component like in the linked example.

Is there any way to set up a notification directly to my Android app, like with Google Cloud Messaging or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using a cloud-based intermediary server that gets the watch notifications from Calendar API and then notifies Android app clients. Google AppEngine is a good solution and immediately solves the need for a valid TLS certificate on the server since your domain would be .appspot.com and immediately supports HTTPS connectivity. Other options would be Google Compute Engine or AWS.

There is no realtime alternative without a web server, you're only option is to perform polling of the resource.